Excel Power Query - Stop query if record field does not exist
I'm running a query which returns a record with a number of fields.
If the record contains the field 'CashField', the query continues as normal. However, if the field does NOT exist, is there a way to terminate the query cleanly and exit the function i.e. not subsequent steps from running?

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CASH_FLOW_QUERY"]}[Content],
    ...
    res = Record.HasFields(Source, "CashField"),
in
    res

Attempted if statements and error handling but no success

Are you really returning a record or a table?
Are there column headers? 
Then it is a table and use
let Source =  #table({"aaa", "bbb","Cash Field"},{{"111","bbb","ccc"}}),
x =  if List.Contains(Table.ColumnNames(Source),"Cash Field") then PutNameOfAnotherQueryorFunctionHere else null
in x

Is it a record?

then
let Source = Record.FromTable(Table.FromRecords({[Name = "aaa", Value = 11],[Name = "bbb", Value = "Bob"],[Name = "CashField", Value = "14567"]})),
x = if Record.HasFields(Source, "CashField") then PutNameOfAnotherQueryorFunctionHere else null
in x


Thank you. It is definitely a record.
When you say “ PutNameOfAnotherQueryorFunctionHere”, do you mean capture your remaining steps (of the query) inside a function which will then return the output to x?

capture the remaining steps inside a function or create a separate query that will only run when true

Thank you, putting the remaining steps inside a function worked!
However, i couldn’t get multiple steps inside an if statement to work! Is there an example?
